# Rails - Auto fill database field based upon change in another field

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a field in my database that contains the user's email. In addition, I have a field that contains the sha1 of the email of the user.

I was wondering if there's a way for me to auto-populate the sha1 field based on any change made in original email field.

Thanks in advance,
Dan

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this using a [before_save callback](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_callbacks.html):

```
class User
  before_save :update_email_sha1, if: :email_changed?

  private

  def update_email_sha1
    self.email_sha1 = generate_email_sha1(email)
  end
end
```